# No me pasa el token al ENDPOINT GET que tengo en el backend

Tags: reactjs, flask, axios, get

escribo porque tengo un problema... necesito pasar un token extraido del localStorage, mediante un metodo GET de axios para que me devuelva una respuesta... adjunto el codigo front-end y el back-end

```
checkLoginStatus(){
    const token = localStorage.getItem('jwt-token');
    return axios.get('http://127.0.0.1:5000/optionally_protected', {
    headers: { Authorization: 'Bearer '+token}, 
    withCredentials: true
      
    }).then(response => {
      //console.log(token)
      console.log("retorno de status", response)
    }).catch(error =>{
      console.log("erro catch", error)
    })
  }
```

En el codigo anterior, cuando hago el llamado de la funcion checkLoginStatus(), extraigo el token que ya tengo almacenado en el localStorage, y necesito pasarlo por el metodo get a un ENDPOINT que ya tengo establecido en la API

Aqui tengo mi endpoint y la respuesta que deberia darme

```
@app.route("/optionally_protected", methods=["GET"])
@jwt_required(optional=True)
def optionally_protected():
    current_identity = get_jwt_identity()
    return jsonify(logged_in_as=current_identity)
```

Se supone que de funcionar debería retornarme un mensaje en la consola similar a esto **logged_in_as: (datos del token)**

por favor ayuda